# How to deploy ASP.NET Core app in subfolder of website in IIS?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, subdirectory

I want to be able to access the ASP.NET Core website with a URL such as:

https://www.test.com/myapp

The app works fine if I do not publish it in a subfolder of the IIS website. If I create a new folder (myapp) under it and publish the site there, I get this error:

HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
Common causes of this issue:

- The application process failed to start
- The application process started but then stopped
- The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port

This is the error in the event log:

```
Application <app> with physical root 'C:\web\' failed to start process with commandline ' ', ErrorCode = '0x80070057 : 0.
```

Is it possible to run the app in a subfolder? If not, then how would I be able to run the site in a way where I can access it with the above URL?

Comment: This is likely because your sub-folder isn't configured as an "Application" in IIS.

Comment: Like the other comment indicates, you cannot host ASP.NET Core app in any folder. When you create an application on IIS for it, make sure you run a diagnostics report to rule out typical mistakes, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: I figured it wasn't possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Well I looked around quite a bit for an answer to the exact same question, figured it out for myself. So here it is for the next person: Click on 'Convert to Application' on the folder in IIS!! Assuming your .net core app is sitting in the 'myapp' folder.

[image]